# Magento 2 - \Magento\Sales\Model\Order trying to fetch items in an order is not working

Tags: sales-order, magento-2.1.7

I am trying to get items of an order and display it in phtml file. But not getting the result.

Below provided is the code which I have provided in block

```
protected $_order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Cubet\RMA\Model\ListReturnsFactory $db,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_session = $session;
    $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
    $this->_db = $db;
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->_order = $order;
}
 public function getOrderItems()
  { 
    $orderItems = $this->_order->create()->loadByIncrementId(000000003);
    $orderItems->getAllItems();
    return $orderItems;
 }
```

and the code provided in phtml is

```
$items = $block->getOrderItems();
print_r($items);
```

but it doesn't print any result. Please help on the same.

Comment: Try using a string as the Increment ID: `$orderItems = $this->_order->create()->loadByIncrementId('000000003');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with orderInterface and get items of order,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->order = $order;
}
public function getOrderItems(){
    $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId(000000003);

    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $product = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $product[] = $item->getName().'||'.$item->getQtyordered();
    }
    return $product;
}
```

in template file,

```
$items = $block->getOrderItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: You can accept as solutions so other users have useful.

Comment: Rakesh, could you tell me how I can pass multiple increment id within loadByIncrementId()?

Comment: you can pass using foreach loop pass $block->getOrderItems($id) in template file and in block  getOrderItems($id). get order data like,     $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($id);

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code to call in template

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Cubet\RMA\Model\ListReturnsFactory $db,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
        $this->_db = $db;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }
     public function getOrders() {        
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');
            return $this->orders;
     }
```