# How can I change the Order Status in Controller. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, controllers, order-status

I'm trying to change the specific order Order Status. for that I tried.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
class Index extends Action
{
/**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
    */
   protected $resultJsonFactory;  
   protected $_orderRepository ;
   public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       Magento\Sales\Model $orderRepository,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
       $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
   }    /**
    * Dispatch request
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
    */
   public function execute()
   {
       $orderid = 256076;
       $_order = $this->_orderRepository->getById($orderId); // it order is not order increment id
       $_order->setStatus('pending')->setState('pending');
       $_order->save();
    }
}
```

but this give me an error which is `Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Sales\Model does not exist` How can I change The **Order Status** from **Pending** to **Processing** and every other order status?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
$orderId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId);
$orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->save();
```

Please check with this code..

Comment: Direct use of Object Manager not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderRepository,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
       $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
   } 


$order = $this->_orderRepository;
$order->load($orderId);
$orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->save();
```

Comment: this error occurs..

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor::create

Comment: need to di compile php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I fixed the issue. remove create(). code tested. try now

Comment: Asad Khan  try this

Comment: now my code is giving me an error 'Order::' is undefined. in your code it is on 3rd line from the end.

Comment: use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

Comment: add code before class

Comment: I also did that but not working for me

Comment: Did you Order::' is undefined this error? again

Comment: now this error is removed now it shows. `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in C:\xamppp\htdocs\annalou\vendor\magento\module-payment\Observer\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php:24 Stack trace: #0`

Comment: Check your module other flow. It does not relate this task

Comment: it is... coz if I remove these few lines from my code then it works perfectly.

Comment: If it's works accept answer

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code of snippet, It will help you**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Index extends Action
{
/**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
    */
   protected $_salesOrder;
   protected $resultJsonFactory;  
   protected $_orderRepository;
   public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       \Magento\Sales\Model $orderRepository,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $salesOrder
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
       $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
       $this->_salesOrder = $salesOrder;
   }    /**
    * Dispatch request
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
    */
   public function execute()
   {
       $orderid = 256076;
       $order = $this_>_salesOrder->create();
       $order->load($orderid);
       $orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
       $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
       $order->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply i ma getting error this when run the controller Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Sales\Model does not exist

Comment: Use Magento\Sales\Model\Order instead of Magento\Sales\Model.

Comment: Please also run whole command: php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Exception #0 (LogicException): AsadTest\Asad\Block\Test does not implement BlockInterface

Comment: now this error occurs.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in C:\xamppp\htdocs\annalou\vendor\magento\module-payment\Observer\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php:24 Stack trace: #0`

Comment: Have you check now ?

Comment: did you just add the `create` in the code?

Comment: Yes I have Changed some Thing

Comment: `Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor::$create in C:\xamppp\htdocs\annalou\app\code\AsadTest\Asad\Controller\ChangeCustomerName.php on line 31`

Comment: actually we do not defined the create function so it take it as a variable...

Comment: Yes use create as function. -> create();

Comment: I also do that as well but then it gives me an error `Invalid method Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor::create`

Comment: Try to use  \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order - reference link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181882/magento-2-magento-sales-model-order-trying-to-fetch-items-in-an-order-is-not or  \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order - reference link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181882/magento-2-magento-sales-model-order-trying-to-fetch-items-in-an-order-is-not?rq=1